# From where drupal get the template? if i don't have one

Tags: theming

I've created a template with the following.

#### myTheme.info

```
name = myTheme
description = Just my theme
core = 7.x
stylesheets[all][] = css/myCss.css

regions[test] = Test
regions[content] = Content
```

#### template.php

```
// Empty file
```

#### css/myCss.css

```
// Some styles
```

Drupal has position content and other blocks, but from where did he gets the template if mine is empty?

Also I get these errors:

> Notice: Undefined index: highlighted in include() (line 126 of Z:\home\test1.ru\www\modules\system\page.tpl.php).
>   Notice: Undefined index: sidebar_first in include() (line 138 of Z:\home\test1.ru\www\modules\system\page.tpl.php).
>   Notice: Undefined index: sidebar_second in include() (line 144 of Z:\home\test1.ru\www\modules\system\page.tpl.php).

It looks like it was used in the core template, but in my newly created template, I get this errors. Maybe I need to override some hooks? Which hooks should I override?

Answer (score 1):

The variables for which you get those errors are the variables that Drupal uses to output the default regions a Drupal 7 theme should have, which are the following one.

```
regions[header] = Header
regions[highlighted] = Highlighted
regions[help] = Help
regions[content] = Content
regions[sidebar_first] = Left sidebar
regions[sidebar_second] = Right sidebar
regions[footer] = Footer
```

The template.php file is not a template file; it's the file containing functions template files use.

When your theme doesn't define a template file, Drupal uses the one defined from the module implementing the theme function. For example, the Node module defines `theme_node()`; if your theme doesn't have the template file used by that theme function (node.tpl.php), Drupal will use the template file that is in [modules/node/node.tpl.php](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.tpl.php/7).

Answer (score 0):

If not provided by the theme, Drupal loads templates from the relevant module folder

1. Node
2. Comment
3. Block

etc...

also the 'system' module folder for some templates such as page.tpl. and html.tpl.php

Your undefined index errors are because your page.tpl.php is attempting to print out regions and variables that aren't defined by your theme.